# How to get a list of SiteCollections with the same name?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2013

I have the following powershell, I am getting all sites ordering by name, but I would like to know if there is anyway to know which sites have the same name>?

```
$sites = Get-SPSite -Limit All
$sites | where { $web.WebTemplate -eq "Client"}
    select Url,$_.Name.ToLower(), $_.RootWeb.Created, $_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientCode"], $_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientName"],$_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientSiteCode"] |  format-table -auto | Sort-Object $_Name -descending
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the sites by their name and filter the count is greater then 1:

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All | 
Group-Object Name | 
Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 1}
```

Comment: I need to normalize the name, because some duplicates the name is with lower case and the duplicated one its with upper case, when I try to use Name.ToLower() it shows a syntax error, expression is expected after (

Comment: this script is killing my server, 8gb of ram used so far and not finished, how can I make sure each site gets disposed in this way?

Comment: I tried this, but  its returning all our 15 thousand site collections!

Comment: Try to add the -NoElement switch to Group-Object but that will remove the group of sites.

Comment: what about the memory? how can I make this command without killing my server and do proper disposing?